# Byte array java xml serialization

Tags: java, xml, serialization, stream, jaxb

I have problem with xml serialization in java. Actually I have to make a xml header to my cryptography program which should look like this:

```
<EncryptedFileHeader>
    <Algorithm>algorithm name</Algorithm>
    <KeySize>key size</KeySize>
    <BlockSize>block size</BlockSize>
    <CipherMode>mode</CipherMode>
    <IV>initial vector</IV>
    <ApprovedUsers>
        <User>
            <Email>mail</Email>
            <SessionKey>session key</SessionKey>
        </User>
    </ApprovedUsers>
</EncryptedFileHeade>
*ciphered data*
```

where ciphered data is out of header.
I have considered a xml beans, but it gives me much overhead data like node properties and attributes like:

```
<void property="approvedUsers">
  <void index="0">
```

JAXB gives pretty nice noode lookout, but every data I pass is converted to Base64. This is the biggest problem.  "ciphered data" and "session key" must be stored in a pure binary format (byte []). Even i use xml beans it is stored like this:

```
<array class="byte" length="428704">
   <void index="0">
 <byte>43</byte>
</void>
<void index="1">
 <byte>93</byte>
</void>
<void index="2">
 <byte>76</byte>
</void>
<void index="3">
 <byte>48</byte>
</void>
<void index="4">
...
```

Another way is JAXB with fast infoset.. but I'm wondering if there's another simple sollution for this problem.

Edit:
Here I found some explanation for my problem/ misunderstanding [enter link description here](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip117.html?page=1)

Comment: To store arbitrary binary data in XML you MUST encode it within the allowable character set. This usually means base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sollution for this problem was to serialize with jaxb the header in one stream and close this. And in next stream serialize to existing header with another stream. To deserialize this just read this as text stream and using regular expression find first ending "", unmarshall it as an object. Check size of this and skipping the header read this file in another stream to desierialize the *ciphered data*.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place any byte in XML, there are restrictions, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML

Answer (score 1):

With a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation your could write an `XmlAdapter` to convert a `byte[]` to any representation you want if the default represenation is not sufficient.

```
public class ByteArrayAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, byte[]> {
    ...
}
```